# AngularJS - Isolate scope from parent to child of child?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following simple three layered markup, with each layer being a directive of its own.

```
<div class="schedule">
    <div class="shift" ng-repeat="shift in schedule.shifts">
        <div class="task" ng-repeat="task in shift.tasks">
```

While I have not shown it in the markup above, I want each layer to be an isolated scope (so `shifts` would be isolated, and the `tasks` are also isolated within the `shifts`).

I have a scope inside the `schedule` class, called `scope.clipboard`. I want to deploy this and allow the `task` to access this `scope.clipboard`.

Since by isolating the `shift`, I need to pass everything that `shift` would have access to, the only way I know how to do this is to pass `scope.clipboard` to `shift` just so that I can then pass it to `task`, ie:

```
app.directive('shift', function()
{
    return {
        scope: { clipboard : '=' }
    }
}

app.directive('task', function()
{
    return {
        scope: { clipboard : '=' }
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way? In other words, if you want to pass an isolated scope from layer-1 to layer-3, do you need to also pass it to layer-2?

Comment: Since each layer has isolated scope, and clipboard is declared inside an isolated scope, there is no way to pass it to your sub-directives (which have transclusion child scope), without manually linking the transcluded contents of each directive to the directive's isolated scope. i.e. using the transcludeFn, which is the 5th parameter passed to your link function. Or. alternatively, declare clipboard in your outer controller scope, and pass it into your directive as an attribute with '=' binding.

Comment: @pixelbits, in your second solution, that is what I am doing right now. The `clipboard` is passed from `schedule` to `shift` and then to `task`. I am not familiar with the transclude option. Which one do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to declare clipboard in your outer controller scope, and then pass clipboard to your directives:

JS

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.clipboard = {...};
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
   <div clipboard="clipboard" class="schedule">
      <div clipboard="clipboard" class="shift" ng-repeat="shift in schedule.shifts">
          <div clipboard="clipboard" class="task" ng-repeat="task in shift.tasks">
```

Note: When you see nested directives in the HTML, you should immediately notice that there is a scope hierarchy - meaning parent scope (ctrl) has a child scope (schedule); the parent scope (schedule) has a child scope (shift); the parent scope (shift) has several child scopes because of ng-repeat.  Since scope inheritance is in play, `clipboard` is visible to all scopes. Now each directive also has isolated scope - it is a sister scope to the child scopes that I just mentioned. You're just passing `clipboard` from the outside scope (resolved via scope inheritance), to each (sister) isolated scope.

In your directives, pass clipboard from your child (transclusion) scope into your isolated (sister) scope using '=' binding:

```
app.directive('schedule', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'M',
        scope: { clipboard:'='},
        link: ...
    }
});


app.directive('shift', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'M',
        scope: { clipboard:'='},
        link: ...
    }
});


app.directive('task', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'M',
        scope: { clipboard:'='},
        link: ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to pass anything from the first layer to the third (using isolate scope and the other techniques you want) you would need to pass it from each to the next.

However, since your parent has no repeats (it's a singleton) you may want to consider moving this out to a service. That's almost always the right choice for shared material anyway, since services are singletons by default, they're injectable (easily testable) and they'll clean all this up. The service doesn't even really need to do anything, just expose a `this.clipboard=...` value that the directives can reference. Then just inject the service into each directive and you're done.